# Should I bother with Unit tests on Established Code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

For unit testing in C#, I see the point from the idea of when implementing a new feature or begning a new solution, its better to start with the unit testing from then.

But when there is a fully fledged solution already established with little or no Unit Tests created, what is the point in testing when there is a more than adequate exception handling in place already ?

Im writing unit tests but fail to see the point when i cant pass through malformed data ANYWAY into anything im testing as i have used ENUM's mostly!

Unless I missing something absolutely crazy.. Am I wasting time going back to older code to integrate Unit Tests ?

Comment: You appear to believe that unit testing is *only* about handling invalid input. It isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing unit tests for existing code is helpful when you're currently or in the future going to work at it. The tests help you make sure that you're not introducing any new bugs or unwillingly change some behavior.

Also, writing tests for existing code can help determining the actual functionality of possibly unknown or complicated implementations.

In the unlikely case of bug-free software that will never be touched by a developer again adding unit tests probably won't help you much. But in any other case it helps document the behavior and establish a safety net for the future.

Oh, and since you mention it: Using `enums` won't protect you from passing invalid arguments in C#.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not wasting time by writing tests for existing code. If you are maintaining the code in any way, it's a good idea to have unit tests in place.

Your main challenge will be the scope of the work -- writing unit tests for a large body of code is not going to be easy and certainly not fun. I strongly suggest that you take an iterative approach. In the initial round, it's probably a good idea to focus on unit tests that provide good class coverage, which is a basic metric that is also a good starting point.

After you reach what you feel is a meaningful level of class coverage, you can expand your focus to the other areas over code coverage.

Using a coverage tool like NCover is going to really help provide some metrics here.